# Throttling on a direct route

Tags: apache-camel

Trying to understand how throttling work is two consumers lead to a direct consumer that does some work and then sends a transformed message onward.

I can specify *throttle* on each consumer, but if the intent is not to overwhelm the destination, can I apply *throttle* to the direct route?

More importantly, would it act just as if it is throttling the 2 consumers, or would it consume and potentially create a "build up" of messages between the initial routes and the direct route?

Maybe, instead of *direct* it has to be *seda*?

**Follow-up question:** Can the throttled messages be flushed out if a graceful-shutdown begins?

[image: Throttling a direct route]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice example [here](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/main/examples/route-throttling) corresponding to your problem - in this case, a JMS consumer + a file consumer, both sending to a same seda endpoint.

You will [notice](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/main/examples/route-throttling/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/camel-server.xml) that a **single** throttling policy is defined, and that each consumer is referring to this policy, so that the final destination is not overwhelmed.

Hope this helps.